# How to create a class based view using a custom form to perform an action on an object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

For a stocktaking interface I want a user to insert a decimal for new amount items in stock. Having this decimal a transaction is issued setting the item from stock taking to the actually value by adding difference.

To do yo I have added a view providing just a field for inserting the decimal

views.py:

```
class StorageItemStockTakingView(FormView):
    form_class = StockTakingForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('storage_item_list')
    template_name = 'pmgmt/storageitem/stocktaking.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        si = StorageItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        si.stock_report(
            Decimal(self.request.POST["amount"]), self.request.user)
        return super(StorageItemStockTakingView, self).form_valid(form)
```

based upon a custom form inside forms.py

```
class StockTakingForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.DecimalField(
        _("Parts now inside storage"),
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=4,
        help_text=_("The amount of currently inside storage place."))
```

The used template is quiet simple:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load semanticui %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ object }}</h1>
<p>{% trans "It will create an Transaction adjusting the amount for items on stock to reported one.." %}</p>
<form method="post" class="ui form segment">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|semanticui }}
  <input class="ui button blue" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This did work with Python2. But when I'm using this on Python3 I'm getting an error

```
2016-12-27 19:17:57,206 django.request 24760 Thread-2 ERROR Internal Server Error: /pmgmt/storageitem/1/stocktaking/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 221, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 161, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 153, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 362, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 380, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 168, in clean
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 151, in run_validators
    v(value)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 310, in __call__
    if self.compare(cleaned, self.limit_value):
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 324, in <lambda>
    compare = lambda self, a, b: a > b
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 148, in __lt__
    return self.__cast() < other
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < decimal.Decimal()
2016-12-27 19:17:57,206 django.request 24760 Thread-2 ERROR Internal Server Error: /pmgmt/storageitem/1/stocktaking/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 221, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 161, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 153, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 362, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 380, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 168, in clean
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 151, in run_validators
    v(value)
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 310, in __call__
    if self.compare(cleaned, self.limit_value):
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 324, in <lambda>
    compare = lambda self, a, b: a > b
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/p3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 148, in __lt__
    return self.__cast() < other
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < decimal.Decimal()
```

So I'm wondering what is the correct way of doing something like this with recent Django-versions in a class-based view context?

Comment: This is not the source of your error, which I see has now been identified, but I personally would use `form.cleaned_data['amount']` as the arg to `si.stock_report` in place of `Decimal(self.request.POST["amount"])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first positional argument to a forms.DecimalField is not the label, but the max value - which is why the error complains about comparing a string (that value) with an int (the actual value of the field).

Generally you shouldn't use positional args with form field classes - use kwargs consistently:

```
amount = forms.DecimalField(
    label=_("Parts now inside storage"),
    ...)
```